# Make regex for exact matching two string words

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on Attribute Routing of Web Api 2 . I am trying to implement a Route which contains a regex

Url should be like this

```
/xyz/sale
/xyz/rent
```

I tried my best and searched alot on google but in-vane . What i tried is

```
[Route(@"xyz/{Type:^sale|rent$}")]
```

But it gives the following error

```
The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' 
was unable to  
resolve the following inline constraint: '^sale|rent$'.
```

here is the screenshot of error 
[image: Error]

Please help me out . Thanks

Comment: you can see it here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: does it work if you use: `[Route("xyz/{Type:(sale|rent)}")]`

Comment: @OGHaza :-( no i tried this but it doesn't works

Comment: I figured the key difference is the use of parentheses around the regex, which the example uses on the page you linked. Perhaps that is how it differentiates regex constraints from other constraint keywords.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas. As Wiseguy says, whatever the solution, it's going to need `()` around it.

Comment: your answer was the same which is @Wiseguy is saying , so that is not working

Comment: Like OGHaza mentioned, i used `[Route("xyz/{Type:regex(sale|rent)}")]` and it works just fine...

Comment: Does the method on which you declare this attribute have a parameter named `Type`? When you look at the two examples under "Route Constraints" on the page you linked in your first comment, you can see that the strings before the colon (the ":") match the names of the parameters declared for the methods. (And do both names match when compared case-sensitively?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
[Route("xyz/{Type:regex(sale|rent)}")]
```

If not try:

```
[Route("xyz/{Type:regex(^(sale|rent)$)}")]
```

Comment: This is the same one you just tried in the comments - so it doesn't work. Can you paste the error it gives though?